# class of slowly varying functions

Tags: probability-theory

The (seemingly) universal example of a *slowly varying* function in extreme value theory is a power of the natural log, e.g. $\lambda (\ln (x))^{a}$ for $x > 0$, $\lambda \ge 0$, and $a \ge 0$. In view of Karamata's representation theorem, can we say *all* slowly varying functions $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $|f(x)|$ $\le$ $\lambda (\ln (x))^{a}$ as $x$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ for $\lambda \ge 0$ and $a \ge 0$?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no.

There are slowly varying functions that grow faster than any power of $\log x$ but more slowly than any power of $x$. Examples are $f(x) = \exp((\log x)^b)$ with $0 < b < 1$.